# How to create the empty selection?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am working a lot with selections that users can modify. I have noticed that bokeh does not distinguish between select all and select nothing. Could this be true?

So for some column data source with data key `x` the following results in identical selections:

```
source.selected.indices = []
```

and

```
all_indices = list(range(len(source.data['x'])))
source.selected.indices = all_indices
```

How do I deselect all elements of a data source?

**EDIT: A minimal working example.**

```
import bokeh.plotting
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource


data = dict(x=[15,2,21], y=[8,8,6])
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

plot = bokeh.plotting.figure()
plot.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source)

source.selected.indices = [0,1,2]
source.selected.indices = [1]
source.selected.indices = []

curdoc().add_root(plot)
```

All circles are visualized as "selected" when `source.selected.indices = []` and **also** when `source.selected.indices = [0,1,2]`. Clearly the selections are different and should not look the same, right?

Comment: I would expect the first one to function, so if you are saying it is not, then what would be helpful is a complete, minimal example script to focus discussion and experiment with.

Comment: @bigreddot I added a mwe.

Comment: Are you asking about just the visual appearance? Then yes, the default action on selection is to "wash out" the *non-selected* points (by lowering their alpha and setting color to grey), but leave the selected points looking the way they were (which stands out against the non-selected points). Is this what you are asking how to change? It's not clear what you want to have happen. The code above runs as expected for me.

Comment: E.g. this statement is false: *but in the first case they should all be drawn with the non selection glyph (alpha = 0.2)* The nonselection glyph only applies to points that are *not selected* but in the first case, *everything* is selected.

Answer (score 1):

The default action on selection is to "wash out" the non-selected points (by lowering their alpha and setting color to grey), but leave the selected points looking the way they were (which stands out against the non-selected points). If you want something different, there is a section in the Users Guide that describes how to configure [Selected and Unselected Glyphs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selected-and-unselected-glyphs). E.g:

```
plot.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=50,

            # set visual properties for selected glyphs
            selection_color="firebrick",

            # set visual properties for non-selected glyphs
            nonselection_fill_alpha=0.2,
            nonselection_fill_color="blue",
            nonselection_line_color="firebrick",
            nonselection_line_alpha=1.0)
```

[image][image]

Comment: I am saying that two very different selections look identical and that this should not happen, right? See my edited question.

Comment: By default, "nothing selected" and "everything selected" look identical. As I mentioned, the default policy only affects the ***NON*** selected points (it washes them out with low alpha and grey).

Comment: If you want to have something different happen than that, I explain how to do that in the answer right above. You can can set the appearance for selected points to be different, as well.

Comment: Or perhaps this is a source of confusion: The concept of selected/non-selected *only* applies when *something* is selected. In that case the non-selected points are exactly the ones that are not selected. If *nothing* is selected, then there is only the *standard* glyph appearance (whatever you specified in the glyph method call). So in other words: the *standard* appearance, and the *selected appearance* are identical, by default. This is why "no selection" (all standard appearance) and "all selection" (all selected appearance) look the same. Most people find this fine. But you can change it